# Use Maps with typerscirpt and requirejs

Tags: google-maps, requirejs, here-api, typescript2.0

I starting using requirejs with typescript and the amd module of typescript.

Right now I am using HereMaps with typescript, the functions are only referenced with a d.ts file.

How could I reference/import Here Maps, google maps or openstreetmaps to typescript 2, that it will be loaded by requirejs?

Comment: Please provide your code for us to help you better

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is not a perfect combination and it will be better to use webpack or something simular

I solved it by switch the typescript module to AMD in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "AMD",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

then you have to use require to import reference

```
import H = require('heremaps-core');
```

after you define external references

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'heremaps-core': {
            exports: 'H'
        },
        'heremaps-ui': ['heremaps-core'],
        'heremaps-service': ['heremaps-core'],
        'heremaps-events': ['heremaps-core'],

        'hogan': {
            exports: 'Hogan'
        }

    },
    paths: {
        'jquery': [
            'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min',
            'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min',
            'lib/jquery-3.1.1.min'
        ],
        'hogan': [
            'https://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/builds/3.0.1/hogan-3.0.1.js',
            'lib/hogan.min'
        ],
        'google.maps': [
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21 &key=AIzaSyBtw3pgNVNPacgQGwLQt1nUbBrqGW-De90'
        ],
        'heremaps-core': [
            'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core'
        ],
        'heremaps-ui': [
            'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui'
        ],
        'heremaps-service': [
            'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service'
        ],
        'heremaps-events': [
            'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents'
        ]
    }

});
```

I am not sure if it is all. I did not work at this project since a year.